# Recording 1080p video on HTC Rezound camcorder using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder

The built-in camera app on the Rezound is able to record video at 1080p, but I'm having trouble doing this from the Android API. Everything works great if I use the settings in CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH, but that only gives me video at 720x480. When I try to increase the resolution to 1080p, my app freezes on MediaRecorder.start() and any app that tries to use the camera stops working until I restart my phone.

Here's the code I'm using to configure MediaRecorder:

```
CamcorderProfile prof = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
if(false){
    prof.videoFrameHeight=1080;
    prof.videoFrameWidth=1920;
}
prof.videoFrameRate=24;
prof.audioCodec=MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
prof.audioSampleRate=44100;
prof.audioBitRate=96;
prof.audioChannels=2;
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(prof);
```

The app freezes when I enable the code inside the if block. I've tried to exactly copy the settings of the videos I get when I record 1080p from the native camera app.

It would be great to track down the source of the native camera app used on the Rezound. I checked out the native camera app in the 2.3.4 release of Android and it doesn't look like it can support any resolution higher than the one specified in CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH.

Answer (score 1):

1920 * 1080 pixels * 3 colors at 24fps is an awful lot of data for a little Android.

Even with hardware H264 compression this is tricky to do in real time on a PC with a fancy capture card

Comment: Agreed, it's an amazing little device. It would be even more amazing if it could do this from the API and not just the native camera app.

Comment: @Kevin - sorry didn't realise the app could do it. It may be setting a lower bit rate (bit rate is slightly independant of profile). You could use http://www.headbands.com/gspot/ to see what the saved video files are using.

Comment: No worries, the description was pretty confusing (edited to clarify). Mediainfo reports that the bit rate is about 7500 Kbps for 1080p video from the built in app. I tried playing with bit rate settings in this neighborhood but the app is still freezing. Thanks for the suggestion.